Strictly convex function for minimization problem
I have the following function $$F\left(x,\lambda,\zeta\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\zeta^2}{\lambda-\mu x}},$$ due to a minimization problem of the kind $\operatorname{min}\int_0^1 F(x,y(x),y'(x)) dx$, i want to prove that there exists an unique optimal solution using E-L theorem, that asserts that if $F$ is strictly convex for $(\lambda,\zeta)$, then the solution for E-L equations (if exists) us the unique optimal solution. To prove it I'm using the fact that fixed $x\in (0,1)$ the Hessian is definite positive, which implies that the function is strictly convex. Indeed. $$F_{\lambda\lambda}=\dfrac{3\sqrt{{\zeta}^2+1}}{4\left({\lambda}-{\mu}x\right)^\frac{5}{2}}>0$$, $$F_{\zeta\zeta}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{{\lambda}-{\mu}x}\left({\zeta}^2+1\right)^\frac{3}{2}},$$ and $$F_{\lambda\zeta}=-\dfrac{{\zeta}}{2\sqrt{{\zeta}^2+1}\left({\lambda}-{\mu}x\right)^\frac{3}{2}}.$$ I computed $$F_{\lambda\lambda}F_{\zeta\zeta}-F_{\lambda\zeta}^2=\frac{3/2\zeta^2+3}{4(\lambda-\mu x)^3(\zeta^2+1)^2}>0,$$ so the function is strictly convex for $(\lambda,\zeta)$. Is correct my reasoning? Thanks in advance!
